# Error when upload project using laravel 5 on host

Tags: html, laravel, upload, package, host

I have download packages laravel 5, and upload it on host http://test.dntc.com.vn/ for test
Result is blank page, no content.Help...

Answer (score 0):

Check your server error_log for exact cause. Often there are storage folder permissions issues or Laravel Apache requirements are not installed.

Read more about requirements from http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#server-requirements

Answer (score 0):

First, enable PHP errors  in your server to see whats happen.

Comment: well,this is not the exact answer of the question,it should be a comment,but you can not leave comments yet.